# How do write several Java codes using Strings and while loop with JOptionPane

Tags: java

I am in beginning Java. I have been trying for several days to figure how to code the following:

Use a while loop to ask for name, phone, and email separated by spaces using a single JOptionPane.

In the loop, check if the user selects OK of Cancel without entering data, if so prompt the user until valid data is entered.

Separate the name, phone, and email into separate String variables.

In the loop, check if the name is 10 characters or less, if not, prompt the user until valid data is entered.

If valid data is entered, create the Contact object using the constructor and name, phone, and email supplied by the user.
Display the contents in a JOptionPane using the get methods.

Even if someone can help me with just the "Use a while loop to ask for name, phone, and email separated by spaces using a single JOptionPane."

and/or

"If valid data is entered, create the Contact object using the constructor and name, phone, and email supplied by the user." code.

I can figure out the rest I'm sure. And yes, I know how to spell Sunflower...the A was on purpose. Thank you to anyone who helps. I really appreciate it!

This is what I have: (the Contact class info is posted below) I am learning how to clean this code up to be more efficient. I was going to delete from about Line 19 on after I figured our how to do the while loop. For now, I get all excited when I actually get a code to work.

import javax.swing.*;
public class TestContact
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    Contact mycontact = new Contact();

    mycontact.setName("Tanya Smith");

    mycontact.setPhone("440-226-2866");

    mycontact.setEmail("tanya@gmail.com");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  
             "The Contact's information is:\n Name: " + mycontact.getName() +
             "\n Phone Number: " + mycontact.getPhone () +
             "\n Email: " + mycontact.getEmail());

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your Name: " );
    while Name.equals()
    String Info = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter you Name, Phone Number and Email");
    String[] word = Info.split(" ");
    String AllInfo =
            Character.toString(word[0].charAt(0)) + 
            Character.toString(word[1].charAt(0)) + 
            Character.toString(word[2].charAt(0)) +
            Character.toString(word[3].charAt(0));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Name: " + word[0] + " " + word[1] +
        "\nYour Phone: " + word[2] +
        "\nYour Email: " + word[3]);

}
```

}

I figured out how to do it one way with the Character.toString, but not with using the while loop.

Comment: Sorry, but please read [ask] and [help] on how to ask a question.

Comment: I don't have any code yet because I don't know where to start on that one. I believe it should be something like while(name.equals()), but I'm confused what would come next

Comment: import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Contact
{
  private String name;
  private String phone;
  private String email;
  
  public void setName(String aName)
 {
   name= aName;
 }
  public void setPhone(String aPhone)
 {
  phone= aPhone;
 }
  public void setEmail(String aEmail)
 {
  email= aEmail;
 }
  public String getName()
 {
  return name;
 }
  public String getPhone()
 {
  return phone;
 }
 public String getEmail()
 {
  return email;
 }
}

Comment: You should edit or OP with your code. Its next to impossible to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't approve of simply asking for code, you do sound legitimately stuck, and confused. I'm also waiting on a 4 gig transfer over a very slow network connection, so here's a bit to get you started. This should get you most of the way. Next time try to post whatever you came up with, regardless of how off base you think it might be. A least we know you're not just asking for code.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    promptForData();
}


public static void promptForData() {
    boolean cont = true;
    while (cont) {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter  name phone and email space delimited.");
        cont = !validData(input);
    }
}

public static boolean validData(String input) {
    String[] parts = input.split(" ");
    if (parts.length != 3) return false;
    if (parts[0].length() < 11) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Even if someone can help me with just the "Use a while loop to ask for name, phone, and email separated by spaces using a single JOptionPane."

Pseudo code

```
String name;
String phone;
String email;
String input;
String[] array;
while name.length() > 10 or name is null
    input = JOptionPane...
    array = input.split(....)
    name = first array index
// end loop
phone = second array index
email = third array index
```

> ""If valid data is entered, create the Contact object using the constructor and name, phone, and email supplied by the user." code."

Pseudo code

```
class Contact
    String name;
    String phone;
    String email
    Contact (constructor taking the three field type arg)
        this field = an argument
        .... // two more
```

After the loop from the first part after get the valid input

```
Contact contact = new Contact( fill in the args)
```